# Change the icon of app with hard-coded icon

Tags: icon

Is there any way to change the icon of an app which has hard-coded icons? I'm talking specifically about SoulseekQt, which overrides any icons set by the user with one inside the code of the app.

Perhaps creating a "wrapper" of sorts? Something like opening the app from an alias, and having the alias icon show for it when opened.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are multiple unique methods outlined in the answers of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/37811/928285).

Comment: I have tried the official, outlined answer, of "pasting" an icon. I believe apps that offer to change the icon through a GUI do the exact same thing. I have also tried replacing the icns inside the package, offered in the linked post as an alternative, to no avail. The app just overwrites both with its hard-coded icons.

Comment: Interesting; I'm sorry, I don't have a working Mac any more to test the methods personally with this app. Can you edit to include the permissions of the `.app` and the other folders leading to the icons? That may help someone else be able to understand why it's failing.

Comment: Sure. How do I find that info?